# Is it Possible to to include only php material and skip html text while including a php file?

Tags: php, html, css, ajax

I have a file that prints a variable from mysql database via php say it is called `independent.php`. if we open the file via localhost/independent.php the file displays the information with html.

Is it possible to include `independent.php` in another php file, and only display the contents generated via php and not the html of `independent.php` so that using ajax the new html appear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use only specific parts of your code, *make it modular*. Break it down into functions and/or classes. Separate the HTML output from the part that fetches data so you can call both independently. There's no other sane way.